# having some issue with the buttons 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'

Tags: java, android

**Hello guys can someone please look into this error I am getting after I run my app :**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.foodapp, PID: 9804
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.foodapp/com.example.foodapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48 in com.example.foodapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #48 in com.example.foodapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3356)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48 in com.example.foodapp:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #48 in com.example.foodapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48 in com.example.foodapp:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1004)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.foodapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7973)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3500)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2049)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 1 to color: type=0x5
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:533)
        at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
        at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
            ... 30 more
```

Here is the main activity code :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_eat_it" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
        android:text="@string/slogan"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `Binary XML file line #48 in com.example.foodapp:layout/activity_main:`
> `Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton`

It seems that your layout can't recognize the [`FButton`][1]

So, make sure to add below dependence to **build.gradle** module file

```
implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
```

UPDATE: wrapping your layout into a singe root ViewGroup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_eat_it" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/slogan"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

  [1]: https://github.com/hoang8f/android-flat-button
```

Comment: @FoxAli there is something wrong in your layout, you have two LinearLayout's as root layouts, and you should have only one root layout, and nest others inside

Comment: So i place everything inside the linearlayout?

Comment: @FoxAli yes there must always be a single outer (top) AKA root layout, of course it can be LinearLayout, or any other types of layouts

Comment: I guess the issue is comign from this : <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

Comment: @FoxAli I just updated the answer. please use the added layout and let me know if it works

Comment: still the same ...when iam using this app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp" its not changing the button color altho i have  <color name="btnSignUp">#39796b</color> in colors

Comment: this is an error different from that of your question.. does your app still crash of the error you posted?